# Passing method parameter (combobox text) using Task factory

Tags: c#, winforms, task

So I'm a little bit confused here. My code looks like this:

```
task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dataTabel_b1 = ConverteerRoutines.GetDataTableVanDatabase(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString_b1, cbSqlTabel_b1.Text));
```

the second parameter (cbSqlTabel_b1) is a combobox on my GUI. When I run this code I get an invalidoperationexcepction. I'll get this message: *It is not allowed to enter through different threads of a process: it was given access to the control cbSqlTabel_b1 from a different thread than the thread on which the element is created.* When I'll do this, it works just fine:

```
String tableName = cbSqlTabel_b1.Text;
task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dataTabel_b1 = ConverteerRoutines.GetDataTableVanDatabase(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString_b1, tableName));
```

So I tried the same thing with a textbox. That would look like the following:

```
task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dataTabel_b1 = ConverteerRoutines.GetDataTableVanDatabase(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString_b1, textBox1.Text));
```

This just works fine as well. Does anybody know why I can't do the same with a comboBox? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running this code in a UI event?

Comment: The task is created in the UI form. The method is running from a seperate (global class), because the method is needed in different forms.

Answer (score 1):

The text box's `Text` property implementation automatically marshals to the UI thread to access the textbox.  The combo box's implementation doesn't do that for you, so you'll need to make sure that you access it from the UI thread yourself, rather than relying on the `Text` property to work from a non-UI thread.  The best way to do so is as you showed, to pull the value from the UI before starting the new task.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to verify that the textbox implementation does the marshaling for you? Just curious, I didn't know this.

Comment: @Logan If it didn't the code wouldn't work.  I would discourage it's use, but the OP's code alone demonstrates that it does.

Comment: It's also possible that this works by some luck or some alignment of some distant moon and our planet and the sun, but you can't say for sure unless you have something to back it up. I'll give it to you that your answer is the most likely reason, but features like this (if it is a feature that is) should be documented IMO (in a perfect world).

Comment: @Logan It does in fact marshal to the UI thread, it is no an accident.  You're more than welcome to search for a documentation of this behavior if you want, and I certainly wouldn't fault you for not relying on this behavior, because, as mentioned, I consider doing so a bad idea for reasons beyond reliability, but that is what's going on.  It's easy enough to prove experimentally by blocking the UI thread and then using the property.

Comment: I just tested it by making a blank form with a textbox, combobox and a button, and showing a message box with the text of the textbox and the combobox one after the other in a task fired when I click the button. You're right, if I freeze the UI thread then my first messagebox with the text of the textbox doesn't appear till I thaw my UI thread. What's weird though is the second messagebox never appears at all no matter what I do where I would have expected it to do the same invalid operation exception OP got. Let this be the documentation then :)

Comment: It doesn't marshals the call to UI thread, it just suppresses the Exception being thrown, Just checked the source.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Blocking the UI thread prevents the call to `Text` from being invoked, which indicates that it *doesn't* just do an entirely unsafe invocation.  Looking through the source a bit it does a few checks to see if it's valid to do an unsafe read, and does the necessary synchronization if that's not the case.  That's likely the cause of your confusion.

Comment: Refer my answer and let me know where am looking wrong. Also which is the method you're referring to *does the necessary synchronization*? If you name the method, it would be easy for me to look into the source.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The source is not entirely in managed code, so you can only see a portion of it.  The trivial experiment shows that when accessing `Text` from another thread it blocks until the UI is free.

Comment: @Servy Fact that it blocks till the UI thread is free is because of `GetWindowText` api call. It will call `SendMessage(WM_GETTEXT,..)`. You might be knowing `SendMessage` is synchronous, that doesn't mean marshaling happens. I believe it is your false assumption, if not can you provide a definitive resource which states marshaling is going on?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Sending a message to the message pump is *the literal definition* of marshaling to the UI thread.  That's what marshaling to the UI thread *means*, to send a message to the message pump, to which the message pump will then perform the message sent to it.  The message pump is pumped from the UI thread (hopefully; assuming you're not doing evil things like pumping the UI thread from a non-UI thread).

Comment: I see what you mean. Sorry for being dumb :( and thanks for your patience:)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `Control.Invoke` when accessing UI elements and you're not on the UI thread. Since your Task you are creating runs on a separate thread, you will need to make use of `Control.Invoke`.

In your second example:

```
String tableName = cbSqlTabel_b1.Text;
task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dataTabel_b1 = ConverteerRoutines.GetDataTableVanDatabase(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString_b1, tableName));
```

If that is running on the UI thread (for example it was fired from a UI event), it will work, because you're hitting `cbSqlTabel_b1` from the UI thread.

I'm not sure why your third example with the text box is working, perhaps someone with more experience than me can answer that.

As you've found and Servy in the comments mentioned, you can fix it simply by getting the value while still in your UI thread before you create your task (which is more efficient since the stuff below means you are jumping threads all the time).

Regardless, to get it working within your task, I would recommend creating a separate method in your UI class/form to get the control's text which will let you forget about ever trying to do a `ControlInvoke` to access something again.

The pattern goes like this:

```
private string GetCbSqlTabel_B1Text()
{
  if(this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    return (string)this.Invoke(new Func<string>(() => GetCbSqlTabel_B1Text()));
  }
  else
  {
    return cbSqlTabel_B1.Text;
  }
}
```

`InvokeRequired` does what it says, it will tell you if you need to use `Control.Invoke` or not. When this method is called from some random thread, it will call itself from within the UI thread, at which point it knows it can directly access the control you need.

Once you've got that method you simply need to change your task to use it:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
          ConverteerRoutines.GetDataTableVanDatabase(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString_b1, GetCbSqlTabel_B1Text()));
        });
```

The only downside I know of to this pattern is you might end up needing to create a lot of these methods, but they work really nicely. They're also nice to assign things to controls, for example:

```
private void SetCbSqlTabel_B1Text(string text)
{
  if(this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => SetCbSqlTabel_B1Text(text)));
  }
  else
  {
    cbSqlTabel_B1.Text = text;
  }
}
```

This time we don't need to return anything so we just use an `Action` instead of a `Func`.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing any of this.  He should be doing what he showed right at the start of his question, pulling the value from the UI before starting the non-UI operation.  He shouldn't be starting the non-UI operation only to immediately marshal back to the UI thread to get this text value.  Of course, your answer doesn't actually answer the question, which is why the second example works while the third doesn't.

Comment: That's also an option :) I just wanted to punt this pattern a bit because I find it extremely useful in other scenarios. I will update my answer with your comment :)

Comment: The pattern is a ton more work, it's far less efficient, it results in more code, more complex code, it's particularly hard to read (you could do what you're doing *far* simpler, although, as mentioned, you shouldn't be doing it at all), it's encouraging poor programming practices (intermingling the UI and business logic tightly), it can fairly easily deadlock when following this pattern if code in these invocations waits on any of the business logic, etc.

Comment: I may be naive but I don't see where business logic is involved when you are setting the text of one control. Of course you can put whatever you want in there and screw up your system if you like, but you could do that anyway with any `Control.Invoke` or any UI event. I would be particularly interested if you can show me better ways of doing this because I use this in all my little utility apps I make and would love to learn better ways, but I don't think the comments are the right place to do that in.

Comment: The "better" way to do it is to do exactly what the OP is doing.  Pull the UI values while in the UI thread before starting the non-UI operation, then pass in those values to the business logic.  It's easier, more maintainable, clearer, faster, reduces coupling, won't deadlock, etc.

Comment: Fair enough, in cases like this where you're already on the UI thread then yes I agree with you. I thought you were talking about other cases, like if I fire off a task to asynchronously get something from a DB and populate a UI field with its contents or if I'm in a callback or something like that.